# What are the products of 1 mol of vitamin C (C6H8O6) and 1 mol of hydrogen peroxide (H2O2)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, redox, reaction-control

Basic stoichiometry suggests that  $\pu{1 mol}$ of vitamin C($\ce{C6H8O6}$) react with $\ce{1 mol}$ hydrogen peroxide ($\ce{H2O2}$) to produce one $\ce{1 mol}$ dehydroascorbic acid DHA($\ce{C6H6O6}$)?

[image]

Other sources suggest that the product of the above chemical reaction DHA ($\ce{C6H6O6}$), is more susceptible to further oxidation than vitamin C  ($\ce{C6H8O6}$), leading to further reduction.

[("Both dehydroascorbic acid and hydrolyzed dehydroascorbic acid (diketogulonic acid) are more susceptible to hydrogen peroxide oxidation than ascorbic acid.")](https://%20https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/9448835/)

**Would the reaction change if it took place in 1 liter of $\ce{H2O}$?**
**How could I control the reaction to produce DHA?**

[image: reference] [See here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01498a057) [image]

Comment: Avoid confusion of O and 0 in chemical formulas. Note that mole is the unit like kilogram, mol is the unit symbol like kg.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your feedback. Why am I getting down voted?

Comment: I corrected capitalisation, but title doesn't exactly match the rest... Hiding bare urls would also be good idea.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: If you quote material, you should include a proper citation, too.